# PySpark RDD programming code with condition for given datasets

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Dataset 1: Employee.txt

```
ID,Name,AGE,SALARY
101,A,21,8000
102,B,22,14000
103,C,23,7000
```

Help to count the number of employees age greater than 25 using PySpark RDD?

Comment: you could read the file as a dataframe and do your operations

Comment: I am familiar with dataframes, was exploring RDD with filters

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `filter` then `count` on RDD:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("Employee.txt")

gt25_count = rdd.filter(lambda x: x != "ID,Name,AGE,SALARY") \
                .map(lambda x: x.split(",")) \
                .filter(lambda x: int(x[2]) > 25) \
                .count()

print(gt25_count)
# 0
```